# Make terminal command use both CPU cores

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, performance, cpu

This may be a bit of a easy question, but I couldn't find anything about it after googling a bit, sorry!

Is there any way to make a command use both of my CPU cores? I am currently processing some PDF files using GhostScript, but whenever I run the command in the terminal, it uses only around 100% of my CPU. I have to run two instances of it to get it to use 200% of my CPU and thus be twice as fast. Even then, for some reason, 40% of my CPU is "idle," according to Activity Monitor, which *may* imply that I can run more instances.

Is there a way to make this GhostScript command use *all* of my CPU to be as fast as possible, without having to manually run multiple instances of the command?

Comment: [Ghostscript Combine PDfs and Multithread/Core](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326247/ghostscript-combine-pdfs-and-multithread-core) may explain the background...

Comment: Oh, I think that would be the problem. Seems like I need to separate the PDFs out manually, then. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the number of PDFs you have to process and the nature of the tasks, you may consider installing [GNU parallel](http://brewformulas.org/Parallel) in brew.

GNU parallel allows you to execute several jobs concurrently. Example:

```
parallel ::: yes > /dev/null yes > /dev/null
```

An example script (containing small errors e.g. line 13 should start with `find` instead of `ind`!) how to use parallel and ghostscript can be found here: [Quick shell script for parallel OCR on PDFs using ghostscript and tesseract](https://gist.github.com/gtfierro/8324883)

Please also check the extensive man pages of parallel.